# How can CCSprite load ImageURL

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ccsprite

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[ImageViewHelper setImageURL:productInfo.ImageUrl forImageView:imageView];
CCSprite *imageSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:imageView.image.CGImage key:productInfo.ImageUrl];
```

`setImageURL: forImageView:` is a multithreaded way, and when I perform to the third step, the `imageView` does not get loaded successfully, because it's done on a separate queue via multi-threading, but `imageSprite` needs the `imageView.image` to be valid.

Comment: Have you tried getting back on the main queue through: `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` to load the image sprite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the data from a back ground thread, please try getting back onto the main queue while loading the image sprite:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});
```